# How to integrate $\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{i\cos\theta}\cos\theta d\theta$?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I was wondering if you could solve this integral for me. I was trying to calculate the wave loading on one cylinder and this integration is part of that.

I tried to assume $u=\cos\theta$ but it does not work. I think the term $\cos\theta$ in exponential function is the main reason for this difficult integration.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: look up bessel functions

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{2\pi}\expo{\ic\cos\pars{\theta}}\cos\pars{\theta}\,\dd\theta =
\left.-\ic\partiald{}{\mu}
\int_{0}^{2\pi}\expo{\ic\mu\cos\pars{\theta}}\,\dd\theta
\,\right\vert_{\ \mu\ =\ 1}
\\[5mm] = &\
\left.-\ic\partiald{}{\mu}\oint_{\verts{z} = 1}\exp\pars{\mu z\ic \over 2}\exp\pars{\mu\ic \over 2z}\,{\dd z \over \ic z}\,\right\vert_{\ \mu\ =\ 1} =
\left.-\partiald{}{\mu}\sum_{m = 0}^{\infty}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}
{\pars{\mu\ic/2}^{m + n} \over m!\,n!}
\oint_{\verts{z} = 1}{1 \over z^{-m + n + 1}}\,\dd z
\,\right\vert_{\ \mu\ =\ 1}
\\[5mm] = &\
\left.-2\pi\ic\partiald{}{\mu}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}
{\pars{\mu\ic/2}^{2n} \over \pars{n!}^{2}}\,\right\vert_{\ \mu\ =\ 1} =
\left.-2\pi\ic\partiald{}{\mu}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\pars{-1}^{n}
{\mu^{2n} \over 2^{2n}\pars{n!}^{2}}\,\right\vert_{\ \mu\ =\ 1} =
-2\pi\ic\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\pars{-1}^{n}{2n \over 2^{2n}\pars{n!}^{2}}
\\[5mm] = &\
2\pi\ic\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{\pars{-1}^{n} \over 2^{2n + 1}n!\pars{n + 1}!} =
\bbx{\ds{2\pi\ic\,\mrm{J}_{1}\pars{1}}}
\end{align}

> The last series is the well known expansion of the
>   [Bessel Function of the First Kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html) $\ds{\,\mrm{J}_{1}}$ evaluated at a value of its argument equal to one.